# Can I pass a .net Object via querystring?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I stucked at a condition , where i need to share values between the pages. I want to share value from Codebehind via little or no javascript. I already have a question here on SO , but using JS. Still did'nt got any result so another approach i am asking.

So I want to know can i pass any .net object in query string. SO that i can unbox it on other end conveniently.

**Update**

**Or is there any JavaScript approach, by passing it to windows modal dialog. or something like that.**

What I am doing

What i was doing is that on my parent page load. I am extracting the properties from my class that has values fetched from db. and put it in a `Session["mySession"]`. Some thing like this.

```
Session["mySession"] = myClass.myStatus which is List<int>;
```

Now on one my event that checkbox click event from client side, i am opening a popup. and on its page load, extracting the list and filling the checkbox list on the child page.

Now from here user can modify its selection and close this page. Close is done via a button called save , on which i am iterating through the checked items and again sending it in Session["mySession"].

But the problem is here , when ever i again click on radio button to view the updated values , it displays the previous one. That is , If my total count of list is 3 from the db, and after modification it is 1. After reopening it still displays 3 instead of 1.

Comment: i need to pass List<int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would so something like this.

```
var stringNumbers = intNumbers.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
var qsValue = string.Join(",", stringNumbers);

Request.Redirect("Page.aspx?numbers=" + sqValue);
```

Keep in mind that if there are too many numbers the query string is not the best option. Also remember that anyone can see the query string so if this data needs to be secure do not use the query string. Keep in mind the suggestions of other posters.

**Note**

If you are using .NET 4 you can simplify the above code:

```
var qsValue = string.Join(",", intNumbers);
```

Comment: Thanks, the same solution reflected in my mind. But becoz of limitation , i was avoiding. Since my list will have max 5-10 values so i think it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could but you would have to serialize that value so that it could be encoded as a string.  I think a much better approach would be to [put the object in session](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/) rather than on the URL.

Comment: i have taken the approach of sessions but its became evil for me. Session values are not updating properly and every time i am getting old values, whenevr i updates the existing session with new one.

Comment: Session is great thing if used properly. If you get errors please elaborate and we'll help you get over them. Passing such things on the query string is much more evil.

Comment: Session have thier useses, but most of the time I try to avoid them like the plague.  From an end user's point of view, having the session time out and losing your work is a horrible experience.

Answer (score 0):

Make the object serializable and store it in an out-of-process session.

All pages on your web application will then be able to access the object.

Answer (score 0):

you could serialize it and make it printable but you shouldn't

really, **you shouldn't**

[The specification does not dictate a minimum or maximum URL length, but implementation varies by browser and version. For example, Internet Explorer does not support URLs that have more than 2083 characters.[6][7] There is no limit on the number of parameters in a URL; only the raw (as opposed to URL encoded) character length of the URL matters. Web servers may also impose limits on the length of the query string, depending on how the URL and query string is stored. If the URL is too long, the web server fails with the 414 Request-URI Too Long HTTP status code.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues)

Comment: I've been pondering this limitation for a while. If the web request is being made between an application and a service, for example (no browser involved) -- does it even matter?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic, i would check documentation of IIS / Apache / other, limitation might be at the server level.

Comment: aye. just for info sake, this is what I found: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Answer (score -1):

I would probably use a cookie to store the object.

Comment: Depending on your application if it is ok you can print an error message. You can't do much disabling cookies, can't get your favorite email too!